# What does WindowCreationError "Failed to create input context" mean with libEGL and ggez?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to program a game in Rust while working through the [ggez tutorial](https://github.com/ggez/ggez/blob/master/docs/guides/HelloGgez.md). Here is my code (src/main.rs):

```rust
use ggez::*;

// game state information goes here
struct State {}

/* Context connects all of the low-level bits for us; GameResult
   tells us if our game is borken */
impl ggez::event::EventHandler for State {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn draw(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let state = &mut State { };
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let c = conf::Conf::new();
    let (ref mut ctx, ref mut event_loop) = ContextBuilder::new("ggez-0", "My Name")
        .conf(c)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    event::run(ctx, event_loop, state).unwrap();
}
```

I expect the compiler to have the following output:

```
   Compiling ggez-0 v0.1.0 (/home/public/devel/rust/ggez-0)
warning: unused variable: `ctx`
 --> src/main.rs:9:26
  |
9 |     fn update(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
  |                          ^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_ctx`
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

warning: unused variable: `ctx`
  --> src/main.rs:13:24
   |
13 |     fn draw(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
   |                        ^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_ctx`

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 17.55s
     Running `target/debug/ggez-0`
Hello, world!
```

followed by a little GUI window popping up.

However, when I run the code, I get this output:

```
   Compiling ggez-0 v0.1.0 (/home/public/devel/rust/ggez-0)
warning: unused variable: `ctx`
 --> src/main.rs:9:26
  |
9 |     fn update(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
  |                          ^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_ctx`
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

warning: unused variable: `ctx`
  --> src/main.rs:13:24
   |
13 |     fn draw(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> GameResult<()> {
   |                        ^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_ctx`

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 17.55s
     Running `target/debug/ggez-0`
Hello, world!
libEGL warning: DRI3: failed to query the version
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: WindowCreationError(Window(OsError("Failed to create input context: XError(XError { description: \"BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)\", error_code: 1, request_code: 155, minor_code: 1 })")))', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

and no GUI window. Googling the verbatim text of the error message didn't help, and I don't understand much of what it is saying. What is going on?

I'm using version 1.34.0 of the Rust compiler, running on Ubuntu 18.10 over SSH with the option `-XC` so that I can get GUIs, and other GUI programs (like Firefox, Writer, etc.) work fine for me. Some forums advised using `sudo apt install mesa-utils-extra` for similar issues, but that changed nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev libgles2-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev` and running the program again fixed the problem.